# Как произвести фильтрацию из дочерней таблицы с максимальной датой в Django?

Tags: django

У меня есть 3 модели в проекте Django:

```
# Железо
class Hardware(models.Model):
    inventory_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True,)

# Подразделение
class Subdivision(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,)

# Перемещения
class Relocation(models.Model):
    hardware = models.ForeignKey('Hardware',)
    subdivision = models.ForeignKey('Subdivision',)
    relocation_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата перемещения', default=date.today())
```

Таблица 'Hardware_Relocation' со значениями для примера:

```
id hardware subdivision relocation_date

1 1 1   01.01.2009
2 1 2   01.01.2010
3 1 1   01.01.2011
4 1 3   01.01.2012
5 1 3   01.01.2013
6 1 3   01.01.2014
7 1 3   01.01.2015 # Сейчас железяка с id 1 хранится в подразделении 3 потому что дата перемещения максимальная
```

Я бы хотел написать фильтр для поиска железа в конкретном подразделении на данный момент. Т.е. нужно знать к примеру, какое железо находится в данном подразделении прямо сейчас.

Я пытался написать фильтр:

```
subdivision = Subdivision.objects.get(pk=1)
hardware_list = Hardware.objects.annotate(relocation__relocation_date=Max('relocation__relocation_date')).filter(relocation__subdivision = subdivision)
```

Сейчас *hardware_list* содержит *hardware* 1, но это не верно (потому что сейчас *hardware* 1 в *подразделении* 3).
*hardware_list* должен быть *None* в этом примере.

Следующий код тоже работает не верно (*hardware_list* содержит hardware 1, для подразделения 1).

```
limit_date = datetime.datetime.now()
q1 = Hardware.objects.filter(relocation__subdivision=subdivision,  relocation__relocation_date__lte=limit_date)
q2 = q1.exclude(~Q(relocation__relocation_date__gt=F('relocation__relocation_date')), ~Q(relocation__subdivision=subdivision))
hardware_list = q2.distinct()
```

Прошу помощи. Можно ли решить проблему без использования вьюх, только средствами Django?

Comment: [order_by в помощь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) `Hardware.objects.filter(...).order_by('-relocation_date')`

Answer (score 1):

```
subdivision = Subdivision.objects.get(pk=1)
hardware_list = Hardware.objects.annotate(
    latest_relocation_date=Max('relocation__relocation_date')
).filter(
    relocation__relocation_date=F('latest_relocation_date'),
    relocation__subdivision=subdivision
)
```

Подразумевается, что не будет несколько `Relocation` одного `Hardware` в один день. Иначе, если `Relocation.id` более позднего `Relocation` всегда больше более раннего `Relocation`, тогда:

```
subdivision = Subdivision.objects.get(pk=1)
hardware_list = Hardware.objects.annotate(
    latest_relocation_date=Max('relocation__relocation_date')
).filter(
    relocation__relocation_date=F('latest_relocation_date'),
).annotate(
    latest_relocation_id=Max('relocation__id')
).filter(
    relocation__id=F('latest_relocation_id'),
    relocation__subdivision=subdivision
)
```

Правда, в этом случае можно обойтись без `relocation_date`:

```
subdivision = Subdivision.objects.get(pk=1)
hardware_list = Hardware.objects.annotate(
    latest_relocation_id=Max('relocation__id')
).filter(
    relocation__id=F('latest_relocation_id'),
    relocation__subdivision=subdivision
)
```